# Android - Making textview auto resizable text to fit layout

Tags: android, resize, textview, text-size

I'm trying to get the size of a text in a textview to use it later in the code.

I have declared a float and my textview as so

```
private float mStartTextSize;
private TextView mWordTextView;
```

and then in my onCreate I have

```
 mWordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextView);
 mStartTextSize = mWordTextView.getTextSize();
```

But as I debug and using my phone, it gets the value of 105 even tho I set it as 30sp in the xml.

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="@string/choose_teams"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:id="@+id/wordTextView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:gravity="top|center"/>
```

Comment: thank you! I appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the size in pixel not sp.

```
getTextSize
float getTextSize ()

Returns
float   the size (in pixels) of the default text size in this TextView.
```

[getTextSize() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize())

you can use this to covert sp/dp to pixel and back without the need of a context.

```
public static float pxToDp(int px) {
    return px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}

public static float dpToPx(int dp) {
    return dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```